# openweather API, problem with reading "lat" and "lon" using geocoding in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, geocoding, openweathermap

I was trying to write a program with node.js , using openweather API. in which user would enter the name of the city, then using provided Geocoding API extracting the latitude and longitude coordinates, and then implementing those coordinates to get weather data from current weather API. but somehow I get an error telling me "lat" and "lot" properties can not be read.

here is what I wrote in node:

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

var apiKey = "-hidden-";

app.get("/", function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname+"/index.html")
})

app.post("/", function(req, res){
    var cityName = req.body.cName;
    var geoCodingApi = "http://api.openweathermap.org/geo/1.0/direct?q="+cityName+"&appid="+apiKey;
    var latitude = geoCodingApi.body.lat;
    var longitude = geoCodingApi.body.lon;
    var openWeather = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat="+latitude+"&lon="+longitude+"&appid="+apiKey;
    res.send(openWeather)
})

app.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log("Server is running on port 3000")
})
```

and this is my HTML code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Open Weather API</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action="/" method="post">
      <label for="">Enter City Name</label>
      <input type="text" name="cName" />
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

and here is the result:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'lat')
```

Also tried not using "body" since It was suggested to me that the output is a string so it doesn't have a body. but doing so resulted in those value to be recognized as "unidentified" and produced the link below:

```
https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=unidentified&lon=unidentified&appid=apiKey
```

Can't figure out what the problem is.

Comment: `geoCodingApi` is a _string_, which doesn't have a `body` property... Maybe you meant to actually _use_ that URL to get some data?

Comment: thanks for the answer, then I mistakenly thought the output was JSON. is there anyway I can tap into lan & lon values? or any other method I could make this work?

Comment: The _output_ from hitting that URL might well be JSON, but **you're not making a request to it**. You're just creating the string.

Comment: The problem is the thing I keep saying it is. Just creating a string that looks like a URL **does not** actually make a request, get the response, and parse the body to get the data you're looking for.

Comment: Ahem. [Using `Fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch). @shahriarshafei

Answer (score -2):

`geoCodingApi` doesn't have a body property. You may try:

```
var latitude = geoCodingApi.lat;
var longitude = geoCodingApi.lon;
```

Comment: Strings don't have `lat` or `lon` properties either...

Comment: weirdly enough I tried that too, but their value ended up being recognized as "unidentified". which resulted in producing the following api link:

https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=unidentified&lon=unidentified&appid="apiKey"

Comment: The answer is not even close to the actual problem. When posting an answer to someone's problem try to execute the code in your head or in an actual environment to avoid mistakes like this.